# How to load a module (not a driver) when a USB device is plugged in

Tags: c, linux, kernel

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include <linux/usb/input.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>

/*
 * Version information
*/
#define DRIVER_VERSION ""
#define DRIVER_DESC "Hello World module"
#define DRIVER_LICENSE "GPL"

MODULE_LICENSE(DRIVER_LICENSE);
MODULE_AUTHOR(DRIVER_AUTHOR);

static void __exit hello_world_exit(void)
{
    pr_debug("Bye!\n");
}

static int __init hello_world_init(void)
{
pr_debug("Hello, USB!");
return 0;
}

static struct usb_device_id usb_kbd_id_table[] = {
{ USB_INTERFACE_INFO(USB_INTERFACE_CLASS_HID,
        USB_INTERFACE_SUBCLASS_BOOT,
        USB_INTERFACE_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD) },
{}
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, usb_kbd_id_table);

module_init(hello_world_init);
module_exit(hello_world_exit);
```

How do I make the kernel load this module load when a USB mouse is plugged in (using the userspace hotplug tools) ? Right now, I have put the hello_world.ko file in /lib/modules/$(uname -r) and run depmod -a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern Linux the functionality for loading drivers/modules (or invoking any other commands) whenever new hardware is detected is handled by `udev`. You will have to write a udev rule for your device that will instruct the kernel to load your module when your device has been detected and the corresponding event has occurred. Read more about it [here](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html).